# Graph $x^2+y^2+z^2/4=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Graph $x^2+y^2+z^2/4=1$

I want to know what would be the graph of the equation

Comment: I suggest starting with what you know about the equation of a sphere: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and then see how your equation compares to it.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

One may recognize an [ellipsoid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipsoid.html), a particular quadric surface. If one chooses a cartesian coordinate system, such that *the origin is the center of the ellipsoid*, and the coordinate axes are axes of the ellipsoid, the implicit equation of the ellipsoid has the standard form:
$$
{x^2 \over a^2}+{y^2 \over b^2}+{z^2 \over c^2}=1.
$$The line segments from the origin to the points $(a,0,0),(0,b,0),\,(0,0,c)$ are called the ''semi-principal axes'' of the ellipsoid.

Can you apply it to the given equation?